# Hide detail View

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I need to hide a detail view that is shown when clicked on a tableviewitem

```
- (IBAction)done:(id)sender {
    [self.delegate OrderDetailsViewDidFinish:self];
}
```

It is all connected up with in the, xib and .h but the view doesnot close, it is loaded via this code and loads great:

```
    //Initialize the detail view controller and display it.
OrderDetailsView *dvController = [[OrderDetailsView alloc] initWithNibName:@"OrderDetailsView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
dvController.selectedOrder = (@"%@",selectedOrder);
[self presentModalViewController:dvController animated:YES];
[dvController release];
dvController = nil;
```

the trouble comes when closing it, please not i ahve all the correct .h in the detail view

Thanks

Mason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you present a controller as a modalViewController then when hiding it you only need this:

```
- (IBAction)done:(id)sender {
    [self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

When you use modals a Parent-Child relation is created between two controller (the newly presented is the child) so you can call the previous controller with `self.parentViewController` from this new controller ;)